# delegation click event working only after the 2nd click forward

Tags: javascript, events, delegation

I'm trying to build and learn native javascript `event delegation`(not sure though) like this

```js
function clicked(d) {
  d.innerText = "clicked";
}
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var foos = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('foo'));
  foos.forEach(function(elm, i) {
    elm.addEventListener('click', function() {
      clicked(elm);
    });
  });
})

document.body.innerHTML = `<div class="foo"></div><div class="foo"></div><div class="foo"></div><div class="foo"></div>`;
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Why is it only working after the 2nd click forward?

I can change my addEventListener code block above with `jQuery on` method to get it to work but i just want to know how to make my code above act similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event delegation uses event bubbling and the `event.target` property to process an event for several child elements with a single event handler attached to their parent (see [this explanation](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) by Andrew Tetlaw and other examples in [this blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) by David Walsh).

In your case, you don't need to add an event handler to each `foo` div since the click event is handled at the document level. You can simply check if the target of the click event has the `foo` class and pass that target element to the `clicked` function.

```js
function clicked(d) {
  d.innerText = "clicked";
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === "foo") {
    clicked(e.target);
  }
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="foo"></div><div class="foo"></div><div class="foo"></div><div class="foo"></div>';
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your click handlers on the divs are not set untill you have clicked the `document` once.

- Remove the click handler on the `document`.
- Write to the dom before trying to select the class

```js
function clicked(d) {
  d.innerText = "clicked";
}

document.body.innerHTML = `<div class="foo"></div><div class="foo"></div><div class="foo"></div><div class="foo"></div>`;

var foos = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('foo'));
foos.forEach(function(elm, i) {
  elm.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clicked(elm);
  });
});
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: sorry @Red Mercury, i intentionally write click handler function before DOM, trying to get the same effect with jquery